# How to solve missing words in nltk.corpus.words.words()?

Tags: nlp, nltk, tokenize, corpus

I have tried to remove non-English words from a text. Problem many other words are absent from the NLTK words corpus.

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
lst = ['I have equipped my house with a new [xxx] HP203X climatisation unit']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Sentences'])
    
import nltk 
nltk.download('words')
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
    
df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(w for w in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(x) if w.lower() in (words)))
df
```

Input: `I have equipped my house with a new [xxx] HP203X climatisation unit`
Result: `I have my house with a new unit`

Should have been: `I have equipped my house with a new climatisation unit`

I can't figure out how to complete `nltk.corpus.words.words()` to avoid words like `equipped`, `climatisation` to be remouved from the sentences.

Comment: `climatisation` is not in the English dictionaries, it looks like a French word, as far as I see. You will probably need to supply your own dictionary here.

Comment: Hello Wiktor, many thanks for your answer. Any code example of code of own dictionary addition ? I tried but I failed.

Comment: `words.extend(['climatisation', 'equipped'])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I tried but gives me the error : "AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'extend'" unfortunately ...

Comment: Then use `update`. `words.update(['climatisation', 'equipped'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
words.update(['climatisation', 'equipped'])
```

Here, `words` is a set, that is why `.extend(word_list)` did not work.